# Why does JSON.stringify() \u30FC to ー

Tags: javascript, json

I tried the code below:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ test: "\u30FCabc" }));
```

It gives the output below:

```
'{"test":"ーabc"}'
```

We know that mainly `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string. And as per JSON std (https://www.json.org/json-en.html) we should be able to store `\u30FC`. Then why `"\u30FC"` is converted to `"ー"`?

Comment: Because `"\u30FC"` _is_ `"ー"`

Comment: `console.log("\u30FCabc")`…

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry i am new to this. as per which specification/standard we convert \u30FC to "ー" and not store it as \u30FC? as JSON spec allows to store it as \u30FC . i am little confused here.

Comment: JavaScript already decodes the character sequence `\u30FC` to its actual unicode character before the string is passed to `JSON.stringify`. If you want `\u30FC` to literally appear in the JSON output you'd have to escape it to prevent JavaScript from processing it: `"\\u30FCabc"`

Comment: The mere string literal you typed into Javascript here is interpreted by Javascript. You've just chosen an alternative way to type "ーabc" into your source code.

Comment: @FelixKling — But then you'll get a JSON representation of the escape sequence (i.e. the JSON will include an escaped ```\```), not a JSON representation of `ー` expressed as an escape sequence.

Comment: @Quentin: Oh right. I guess this will only work then if you write the JSON manually (_shudder_)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then why "\u30FC" is converted to "ー" ?

1. The JavaScript engine reads your string literal and does that conversion to create the in-memory string
2. The object containing that string is passed to `JSON.stringify`
3. `JSON.stringify` encodes the object as JSON and represents the `ー` as a literal `ー` because `JSON.stringify` was written in such a way to prefer literal characters over escape sequences where the JSON data format allows either.

Some JSON encoders let you control this, for example, in PHP, compare:

```
<?php echo json_encode('ーabc', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo json_encode('ーabc'); ?>
```

… but JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` doesn't have any such option.